# Adjusting height of GWT Panels based on content

Tags: gwt

We have many screens where different types of GWT panels are used.

One common problem across many screens is that, content size is derived at runtime. So, if I define a height for a panel(Vertical/Horizontal/DockPanel) and when any new components are getting added within panel or content is more, panel height remains the same. So we are not able to see the contents. UI look and feel becomes worst.

How do we handle the height problems? Do we have to manually code to adjust every panel/widget height when something gets changed in screen. Is it not a very bad way of coding? 
Also, now we have datagrids at some places, if no of records are very less, we see a huge space left out below datagrid, not sure how do we handle these cases?

Updated below with few examples as per the comment:
Do you mean to say that whenever we know that content grows vertically, we can always choose FlowPanel. Because, some of the screens we have used Vertical panel/Horizontal Panel and inside that when user clicks something a new fields getting added and shown. So Vertical Panel/Horizontal Panel height automatically not getting adjusted. One more example is that we have main Vertical Panel within a Dock Layout Panel content area and inside that there are some widgets whose content may vary. So now if I use a FlowPanel to the content which varies in size, what about outer panels? Will get it adjusted? Again to say the kind of panels we have used - Dock Layout Panel is used with fixed header, footer, left menu and Content area. A scroll panel is used within Content area. All our different widgets go inside this which is mix and match of horizontal/vertical/datagrids..etc.

Comment: Impossible to understand the problem without knowing the details, which you have not provided. What panels are you using? Why do you have fixed heights? A simple `FlowPanel` widget will behave exactly like an HTML `<div/>` element, so it will grow vertically with content.

Comment: i have updated my query with your answers. Can you please advice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In GWT (and HTML) you can either set the height of a panel or let it expand naturally. In general, once you set the height of something, you lose the ability to let it expand naturally.

Some Panels in GWT implicitly set their own height (or require that you set their height) and so are never good choices for dynamically sized content.  LayoutPanels and ScrollPanels, for example, can never adjust dynamically, and expect you to provide size information programmatically.  FlowPanels and HTMLPanels, on the other hand, are great for dynamic heights and would rather you not set their height explicitly.

If you want a scrolling panel, of course you have to define how high it should be - how else could it know when to scroll and when to just get bigger?  But, you can put a FlowPanel (which expands automatically) inside a ScrollPanel (which you have set at 800px or whatever).  Then, as you add content to the FlowPanel, it will expand inside the ScrollPanel.  Users can then scroll to see different parts of the FlowPanel.

Trouble-shooting tips:

1. Make sure you aren't setting the height on panels that you want to expand naturally
2. Make sure you ARE setting the height on panels that should always be the same size
3. Try using FlowPanels instead of Horizontal/VerticalPanels
4. *LayoutPanels and AbsolutePanels always need explicit sizes and can never grow dynamically as you add more content.  Anything you want to grow with content should probably be a FlowPanel or HTMLPanel.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable inputs :) I am changing the screen panels as per your suggestion, its working nicely :)

Comment: Good :) I remember suddenly understanding how the layout works in GWT, and everything seemed much simpler.